# Android Studio : Size of the release apk of a watch face does not goes under 6Mo

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os, watch-face-api

I found out that every watch face i made did have a release apk file that never goes under 6Mo.
Even when it does not contain any drawable.
Even the default watch face project is about 6Mo once published & signed.

I assume it is an issue of Android Studio, because some watch face on the store are far lower than 6Mo (ex: Circles Watch Face is about 1.9Mo!!)

I found out that in the intermediate manifest of the mobile package, the following lines are added by the merger:

```
    <activity
        android:name="android.support.v7.widget.TestActivity"
        android:label="RecyclerViewTestActivity" />
```

Even with a "tools:node="remove"", it is still added. And with this activity are added a full bunch of ressources (png, values) that I did not use.

[image: Exemple of directories added]
[image: Content of one ressource directory]

Build.gradle of mobile package:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "fr.test"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
wearApp project(':wear')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
compile "com.google.android.support:wearable:1.1.+"
}
```

Did someone experienced the same issue and is there a solution to avoid this or reduce the apk size (an option I missed...)?

Comment: Please show your build.gradle contant

Comment: I added the mobile build.gradle.

Comment: What kind of unit is "Mo" supposed to be?

Comment: Sorry, I'm french. It is similar to Mbytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There 2 ways to go:

1. Reduce size using only needed parts of [GP services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview):

   - Google+  com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.5.0
   - Google Account Login 
     com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.5.0
   - Google Actions, Base Client
     Library  com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.5.0
   - Google App Indexing
     com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:7.5.0
   - Google App Invites
     com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:7.5.0
   - Google Analytics 
     com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0
   - Google Cast  com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:7.5.0
   - Google Cloud Messaging   com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0
   - Google Drive com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:7.5.0
   - Google Fit   com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:7.5.0
   - Google Location, Activity Recognition, and Places
     com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0
   - Google Maps  com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0
   - Google Mobile Ads    com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0
   - Google Nearby    com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:7.5.0
   - Google Panorama Viewer
     com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:7.5.0
   - Google Play Game
     services com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:7.5.0
   - SafetyNet     com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:7.5.0
   - Google Wallet    com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:7.5.0
   - Android Wear  com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.5.0
2. Use [proguard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) - it will cut all unused code

   ```
    buildTypes {
       release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
   ```

Comment: I managed to drop down from 4.7Mbytes to 2.9Mbytes on a simple project with only a wear package, and a mobile package empty.
I think it is still heavy, when I see some other faces on the store that are around 1.9Mbytes, with wear & mobile package used.

Comment: minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true
With this 2 options I was able to get a 1.8MB sized apk. I have to test it to see if everything still works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It includes google play services for wareable library, which is large itself. You can reduce the size by using ProGuard.

Comment: I have added some screenshot to illustrate the ressource I find in the intermediates directory.

Comment: @ThomasThomas try to set minifyEnabled true i n your build.graddle. this will enable proguard